# How to find out which data breach my password was in?

Tags: passwords, data-leakage, breach, have-i-been-pwned, data-breaches

HIBP and my password manager both claim that a password that I am using has been seen in a data leak.
Neither of them provide information about which data leak exactly my password was seen in.

The password is complex and not reused, and I have been using it with a company that has all kinds of my info, including SSN and financial information.

This company has not notified me of any data breaches, which I believe is against the law for them to knowingly conceal--if the password indeed came from my account with that company and not from some other person by some wild coincidence.

How can I verify where my password got leaked from?
Are there any checkers that pinpoint to a specific leak/breach (similarly how HIBP points to who your email was leaked by)?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm afraid just changing your passwords is the best approach, since you might need to delve into the darknet to get more info and it might not be reliable and you might also "end up on a list". Unless the stolen credentials are biometric data, then you're in trouble.

Comment: @SirMuffington If the answer is "there is no reputable service that provides the information", then that is the answer. But this is a real risk. For some services, it may not matter - proactively changing the password may be enough. But if a service that holds key personal or financial data was breached and they have not acknowledged it, one may want to do things like request new credit card numbers or pay closer attention to identity monitoring services. It does seem a bit wrong to say that just changing a password is sufficient, especially in this particular case of good password hygiene.